# Reset tab content scroll position on tab change

Tags: javascript, angular, tabs, primeng, tabview

I'm using PrimeNG TabView, i have enabled vertical scrolling inside the tab content, the problem is that when I change tab, the content horizontal position is the same as the previous. I'm only using JS/TS, CSS, HTML, PrimeNG for the tabs and Ionic Framework.

I want the content of the new selected tab to be at the initial state, "unscrolled"

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example (e.g. in Stackblitz)?

Answer (score 0):

[@FabianStrathaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17298437/fabian-strathaus) It is more efficient to look directly at the code in [this](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/tabview) official documentation, it is what I used, plus however I added this CSS:

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-tabview-panels {
    height: 38vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

looking at the documentation again I maybe figured out what the problem might be, I set horizontal scrolling to p-tabview-panels, maybe I should have set it to p-tabview-panel, the differences:

- p-tabview-panels are the Container panels.
- p-tabview-panel is the Content of a tab.